# FileSystemWatcher not detecting folder creation

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am creating an application that will watch for file changes in a directory although while files with an extension are detected, folders are not.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace fileSystemWatcherTest
{
    class myClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Watching folder");

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                | NotifyFilters.FileName
                | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            watcher.Changed += onChanged;
            watcher.Created += onCreated;
            watcher.Error += onError;

            watcher.Filter = "";
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void onChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
            {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");

            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);

            if (fileExtension != string.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileExtension);
            }
        }

        private static void onCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Created: {e.FullPath}");
        }

        private static void onError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            printException(e.GetException());
        }

        private static void printException(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"StackTrace:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                printException(ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the documentation and the intellisense directories should be detected.

[image]

I believe that the problem is with the Filter property but i can't get it to work so i would appreciate some help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'while files with an extension are detected, folders are not' and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Every file except for folders is detected, Compressed folders are detected though because they have the .zip extension. I want that my program other than detecting files detects folders creation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect directories as well, you need to add `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName` to `watcher.NotifyFilter`:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
    | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
    | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
    | NotifyFilters.FileName
    | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
```

Checkout the [documentation of `NotifyFilters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.notifyfilters?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Thanks i missed that filter when reading the documentation...